# Multi dimensional array with get image data

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused with an array im making, its gotten a bit confusing to follow but i believe its the only way for me to approach what im trying to do.

My idea here is to store getImageData in an array so i can link each image to an array of data.

This is how i create my array:

```
var listObj = {
    id: uid,
    extra: [
            ctx2.getImageData(abposx,abposy,imgwidth,imgheight)
        ]

    };
pixeld.push(listObj);
```

So now im trying to run through the array "pixeld" to find the uid but i don't know how the syntax should be.... this is what i tried:

```
for (j = (pixeld.length-1); j > -1; --j){
        if(pixeld[j].extra.data[3] !==0){ //line 220
            matches.push(pixeld[j].id);
        }

    }
```

The problem is i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined on line 220
```

I have marked which line is 220 in the for loop.

Any one know what my mistake is ?

Comment: What did you expect that `pixel[j].data[3]` to produce?

Comment: An integer value as this example shows: http://www.paste.to/MzYxNDc1. That is related to a specific pixel in that example, mine is an array of the data  or should be =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your structure look like the following:

```
var pixeld = [];  // an Array
var listObj = {}; //an Object

listObj = {  // literal notation
   id    : uid,
   extra : [ ctx2.getImageData(abposx,abposy,imgwidth,imgheight) ]
}
```

Now the question is: What is `ctx.2.getImageData()` returning? You need to clarify that.

Until `pixeld[j].extra` everything is fine, but there is no `data`-property. If `getImageData()` really returns an array, you should be able to access like this:

```
 pixeld[j].extra[3]
```

Comment: From what i googled getImageData returns an array of information about the given area of the canvas which i worked out from this http://www.paste.to/MzYxNDc1

Comment: Unfortunately you can't judge from the code you have there. Try the following: Try `pixeld[j].extra[3]`, if that does not work, do a `console.log(pixeld)` and examine the object. This should give you a hint about the structure. (I assume you have webdevelopertools like firebug in FF?)

Comment: Another question: what do you want to achieve by `pixeld[j].extra.data[3] !==0` if all you need is the id. Perhaps you can just omit the if-condition.

Comment: The concept is .. getimagedata is a canvas function which returns pixel information. the data[3] is made by the getimagedata function which holds the alpha channel value.. if the alpha is not 0 then there is an object there... i don't know how getimagedata structures it as theres no documentation... console log shows: http://tinyurl.com/7odpd2m

Comment: If it  didn't work out yet, try Davids Hint and drop the `[]` of that `extra:[ctx2.getImagedata(...)]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to reference `.extra` as an object, but you have it declared as an array with a single value inside (what `ctx2.getImageData` returns).

Simply drop the spurious `[]`'s surrounding the `ctx2.getImageData` function call and you'll probably fix it.